Running a VPN server through a VPN client
Ok, I know a bunch of similar questions have been asked here before, but Ive read a lot of them and their answers and couldnt really find what Im looking for.
I have a router running OpenWRT and I have a VPN service (Kaspersky) that I use. On my router I have OpenVPN installed and configured as a VPN client connecting to the Kaspersky VPN server.
What Id like to do now is having a VPN server running on the same router that I can use to connect eg my phone to my home network from anywhere away from home.
I have tried already and while I can setup a VPN server to run alongside the VPN client on the same router with no issue (as long as Im using a different port for it of course), I then cannot connect to that VPN server at all.
To be clear, the goal is to be able to connect my phone to my home network from anywhere in the world (provided the phone has a internet connection of course) and to simultaneously have all network traffic between my home network and the public internet go through the Kaspersky VPN service.
Afaik it should be possible to do this. At the very least it should be possible with split tunneling, having the connection to the VPN server on the router run outside the other VPN, but would it also be possible to run the VPN server through the VPN client connection?
And most importantly, how do I need to set this up to make it work?
I imagine the problem with running one VPN through the other would be that I have no idea what ports would be open on the Kaspersky VPN server that could be used for this.
Obviously since both are running on the same router, they need to use different ports...
It would be nice to have the VPN to my home network to go via the Kaspersky VPN though as that almost certainly has a static public IP while the IP my router gets from the ISP is almost certainly dynamic, and therefore would require changing the IP in the configuration on my phone whenever the ISP decides to give my router a new public IP....
Does anyone here know how to set this up?

First thing first, the fact that your router is working as a VPN client does NOT mean that if you try to make some connection to its public IP (configured on its WAN interface) you would be magically connecting "through" that VPN tunnel. It's just that replies for those connection would be "unexpectedly" routed to the tunnel, which is why you need to "split tunnel". But in this case you can't "split" based on destinations (unless you always connect to it with the same source IP), but based on e.g. source port or connection (fwmark + ct mark). See ip rule for such policy routing.

yeah I know that. What I would like to do is to use the public IP of the kaspersky VPN to connect to my router (sending the request through the tunnel as well) as that has a static IP where my routers public IP is dynamic.

while the IP my router gets from the ISP is almost certainly dynamic I don't know why you think commercial VPN almost certainly has a static public IP, let alone that it would be dedicated for your own use and allow you to port forward there. (IIRC some does offer such "premium" option, but not Kaspersky with a quick search. But even when it is possible, I'm not sure I see the sense in such setup.)

how do you think my router connects to the kaspersky vpn? I have a .ovpn file that I got from kaspersky which has an IP address of the vpn server in it. In many months that I have had this running, I never needed to replace the ovpn file, so the vpn servers IP address has not changed.
If I use split tunneling and use my routers public IP when connecting to the VPN server on my router, then one day (which might be any random day) this will just suddenly stop working because the ISP will have assigned my router a different IP...

You need the IP address of the VPN server to connect to it and while eg a windows client application might be able to eg contact a specific server to request the newest IPs for the available VPN servers, an openvpn client running on the router does not and cannot do this. It is configured to connect to one specific IP address and thats what it connects to. if the VPN servers IP would suddenly change, the connection would drop and openvpn would be unable to reestablish it...

Technically the IP you connect to the server does not have to be the IP (of client access) seen by the Internet (i.e. "whatsmyip"). In fact, it's usually considered a bad thing for a commercial VPN to keep using one same IP for a (fixed) bunch of customers. As I said, if you are actually offered a dedicated IP and port forwarding service, then you'll need to configure on the Kaspersky side (and maybe seek help from theif CS). And again, either way, for your goal, probably solution/approach like DDNS or tailscale would make more sense and work much better.

If cost is not a concern, you may even want to replace the Kasperkey VPN with a VPS (or some SaaS whatsoever that is cheaper but allow you to set up a VPN server).
